# Change datetime to timestamp in bash script

Tags: bash, date, timestamp

I have a json in file myTime
{
  "beginTime": "2014-Mar-19 02:15:00",
  "endTime": "2014-Mar-29 02:00:00"
}

I want to get beginTime and change it to timestamp.

I get beginTime by the following code:

```
beginTime=($(jq -r '.beginTime' myTime))
```

I replace Mar by 03 :

```
beginTime=($(echo "$beginTime" | sed -r 's/[Mar]+/03/g'))
```

I change it to time stamp :

```
date -d "$beginTime" "+%s"
```

I got 1395162000 , it mean only change 2014-03-19 because $beginTime give 2014-03-19 , first element of array.
so I tried another code

```
date -d "${beginTime[@]}" "+%s"
```

now I got

```
date: extra operand `+%s'
```

but this code is ok

```
date -d "2014-03-19 02:15:00" "+%s"
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use array variables - you need to capture date and time as a single string:

```
beginTime=$(jq -r '.beginTime' myTime | sed 's/Mar/03/') # "2014-03-19 02:15:00"
```

Note that I've combined your first two commands into one.

(As an aside: regex `/[Mar]+/` happens to work in this case, but is not what you intended - use `/Mar/` instead. `/[Mar]+/` matches any span of at least length 1 composed of any of the following characters in any sequence: `M`, `a`, `r`.)